# Include previous element on wrapAll()

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to target `h3` and include it on my wrap all.
This is my current code to target it.

`$('.perk:first-child').prev().addClass("perk").text("success");`

Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.perk:first-child').prev().addClass("perk").text("success");
  $(".perk").wrapAll("<div class='new' />");
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Perk Rule</h3>
<div class="perk">Test1</div>
<div class="perk">Test2</div>
<div class="perk">Test3</div>
<div class="selected">Selected Perks</div>
```

Comment: all code in OP not in an external link.. external may rot and may cause the OP to be useless to future readers

Comment: `$('.perk:first-child')` doesn't select anything, because `<h3>` is the first child (assuming they're both children of something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(".perk:first-child")` isn't selecting the first `.perk` DIV. Since `<h3>` is before it, it can't be the first child of whatever element contains them both. This selector means *element that has class `perk` and is also the first child*, it doesn't mean *the first child with class `perk`*.

If you want to select the `<h3>` that precedes the first `.perk`, just select all `.perk` and then use `.prev('h3')`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.perk').prev('h3').addClass("perk").text("success");
  $(".perk").wrapAll("<div class='new' />");
});
```

```css
.new {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Perk Rule</h3>
<div class="perk">Test1</div>
<div class="perk">Test2</div>
<div class="perk">Test3</div>
<div class="selected">Selected Perks</div>
```

Comment: or use `$('.perk').eq(0)` which `Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.`

Comment: @guradio That won't match all of them in different DIVs.

Comment: problem if you dont specify the index what if there is an `h3` sandwich between `.perk`? i think the index is important

Comment: I'm assuming he doesn't mix them up like that. But I'm assuming he needed `:first-child` because this pattern repeats in multiple places.

Comment: @guradio thank you that's what I'm thinking as well.